# Why copy-constructor is not called but default constructor is invoked in this code?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have an understanding that copy constructor will be called when an object is created from an already existing object and also when a function returns object by value. So why in the below code the copy constructor is not called but the default constructor?

```
class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "A" << endl; }
    A(A &) { cout << "A&" << endl; }
    A(const A &) { cout << "const A&" << endl; }
};
A fun() {
    class A a;
    return a;
}
int main() {
    class A a = fun(); // output: A
}
```

Comment: If you google for "copy constructor not called", you get many existing answers to this question.

Comment: see [Copy elision - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

Comment: Its because of 'Return value optimization'. Just turn off all optimizations and then test.

Comment: [Nitesh Chordiya](http://stackoverflow.com/users/194372/nitesh-chordiya), turning off all optimizations using **g++ -O** switch did not change the result

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: compiler optimizations.

- First, the `a` object from your function is created directly in the scope of the `main` function, in order to avoid having to copy (or move in C++11) the local parameter out of the scope of the function via the function's return. This is **return value optimization**.
- Then, in main, the statement becomes equivalent to `class A a = A()` and again the compiler is allowed to the create the `a` object in place, without copying from a temporary object. This is **copy elision**.

This is allowed even if the copy constructor (which is bypassed entirely) has side-effects, like in your example.