# Constructor is not called in this aggregation class

Tags: c++

```
class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "A()" << endl; }
};
class B {
public:
    A a;
    B(const A& a1) : a(a1) { cout << "B(const A&)" << endl; }
    /* B(const A& a1) { a = a1; cout << "B(const A&)" << endl; } */
};
int main() {
    B b(A());  /* no ouput */
}
```

No output is generated for the above code. Is that due to the compiler optimization (copy elision) as discussed in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700107/why-copy-constructor-is-not-called-but-default-constructor-is-invoked-in-this-co)?

But if I have a B class constructor and re-write the code like below:

```
class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "A()" << endl; }
};
class B {
public:
    A a;
    B() {}
    B(const A& a1) : a(a1) { cout << "B(const A&)" << endl; }
    /* B(const A& a1) { a = a1; cout << "B(const A&)" << endl; } */
};
int main() {
    B().a; // gives output A()
}
```

Comment: `B b(A());` That's a function declaration. Search for "most vexing parse".

Answer (score 3):

add an extra pair of parentheses:

```
B b((A())); 

// you can also fix it using new C++11 initialization syntax:
B b{A()};
```

the problem you are facing it called most vexing parse, and it means compiler is not able to decide whether you want a function declaration or variable definition.

[edit]

I should also add that standard requires compiler in such case to choose function declaration.

[edit]

clang is actually more helpfull in this case, and gives hint to use partentheses:

http://rextester.com/PECQ53431

```
source_file.cpp:16:8: warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
    B b(A());  /* no ouput */
       ^~~~~
source_file.cpp:16:9: note: add a pair of parentheses to declare a variable
    B b(A());  /* no ouput */
        ^
        (  )
```

1 warning generated.

Comment: "compiler is not able to decide" That's not true. It knows perfectly well.

Comment: @jrok Well, speaking precisely, the compiler is *not* able to decide which one you *want.* It only knows perfectly well which one you *wrote.* ;-)

Comment: @jrok Eh, the syntax is ambiguous a standard says, that in such a case it should pick "declaring a function".

Comment: @Angew Exactly :) Xarn, yeah, but compilers know the standard :)

Answer (score 1):

```
B b(A());
```

Is ambiguous and may be interpreted either as a variable declaration or as a declaration of a function that returns a restult of type `B` and takes a single unnamed parameter of type a function with no parameters and returns a result of type `A`. Although you may think first one should take place the standard dictates in fact the second one will happen. See the article about [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) in wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating A object after B object creation, create first A`s` object in main.

```
A a;
B  b(a);
```